# How to get the last table from this site?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, ng-view

I'm trying to get the last table from this [site](http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/#/enviarFormularioEncerramento?type=dmlldw%3D%3D&ofertaId=OTMx&state=eyJhbm8iOiJNakF4Tmc9PSIsInZhbG9yIjoiTVRFPSIsImNvbXVuaWNhZG8iOiJNUT09Iiwic2l0dWFjYW8iOiJNZz09In0%3D) with python. Below you find my actual trying to do it.

The table is named as "Dados Colocação, nos Termos do Anexo VII da Instrução CVM nº 400, de 2003".

```
lin_cvm_oferta = 'http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/#/enviarFormularioEncerramento?type=dmlldw%3D%3D&ofertaId=MTE3NDE%3D&state=eyJhbm8iOiJNakF4T0E9PSIsInZhbG9yIjoiTVRVPSIsImNvbXVuaWNhZG8iOiJNUT09Iiwic2l0dWFjYW8iOiJNZz09In0%3D'
html = requests.get(lin_cvm_oferta).text
print(html)
```

And when I print the html it doesn't get any of the data.

The first part of the table I already got with Json as my friend @JackFleeting helped me in this other question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58206321/how-can-i-get-the-link-from-this-table-content-i-guess-its-javascript-with)). PS: I know that there is a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302676/how-do-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamically-generated-urls-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1). But I don't want to use Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is different from your previous question - the page uses the `post`, not `get` method. You have to use the developer/network/xhr tool in your browser to extract the url and the payload, and then post it like this:

```
import requests      
import json  

url = 'http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/comunicado/getUltimoComunicado'

payload = {"id":931,"dataInclusao":"2016-05-20T09:26:00Z", "dataInicio":"2016-05-18T00:00:00Z","dataEnceramento":"2016-07-05T00:00:00Z", "numeroEmissao":1,"quantidadeSerie":140,"valorMobiliario":{"id":11,
    "dataInclusao":"2015-12-01T00:00:00Z",
    "descricao":"CERTIFICADOS DE RECEBÍVEIS IMOBILIÁRIOS - CRI",
    "relacionadoFundoInvestimento":False,"situacao":"ATIVO"},
    "tipoEspecie":{"id":3,"descricao":"Sem Preferência"},
    "tipoClasse":{"id":4,"descricao":"Não Aplicável"},
    "tipoOferta":{"id":1,"descricao":"Primária"},"tipoForma":{"id":3,"descricao":"Nominativa e Escritural"},"ofertante":{"id":1860,"nomeResponsavel":"RB CAPITAL COMPANHIA DE SECURITIZAÇÃO","cnpj":2773542000122,"paginaWeb":"http://www.rbcapital.com/","tipoSocietario":{"id":4,"descricao":"Sociedade Anônima de Capital Aberto"}},"emissor":{"id":1859,"nomeResponsavel":"RB CAPITAL COMPANHIA DE SECURITIZAÇÃO","cnpj":2773542000122,"paginaWeb":"http://www.rbcapital.com/","tipoSocietario":{"id":4,"descricao":"Sociedade Anônima de Capital Aberto"}},"lider":{"id":931,"nrPfPj":17298092000130,"dataRegistro":"1998-10-15T00:00:00Z","codigoTipoPessoa":"PJ","codigoTipoParticipante":12},"instituicoesIntermediarias":[{"id":1089,"nrPfPj":59588111000103,"dataRegistro":"1991-08-12T00:00:00Z","codigoTipoPessoa":"PJ","codigoTipoParticipante":12,"denominacaoSocial":"BANCO VOTORANTIM SA"},{"id":1090,"nrPfPj":90400888000142,"dataRegistro":"1990-12-20T00:00:00Z","codigoTipoPessoa":"PJ","codigoTipoParticipante":12,"denominacaoSocial":"BANCO SANTANDER (BRASIL) S.A."}],
               "valorPrecoUnitario":"1.000,00","inativo":False,
               "qtdValoresMobiliarios":0,"valorTotalOferta":0,"variasSeries":True}


headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)    
data = json.loads(resp.content)
print(data)
```

Note that, depending on your IDE, you may have to manually change boolean values to `True` and `False` (uppercase, as I did above), although the site's post request itself uses lowercase.

Comment: My friend! It was exactly what I needed. Tks a lot anda have a Nice weekend..

Comment: @FelipeRibeiro - Thanks and same to you.